# Linking DialogFlow to a Desktop Application

Tags: dialogflow-es

i just started on a project in DialogFlow and i was wondering is it possible to link my dialogflow to a specific desktop application? And if possible, what is the solution?

For example:
By saying "launch app", it will open up the desktop application "app"

Answer (score 0):

While this is certainly something that Dialogflow's APIs can help with - this isn't a feature provided by Dialogflow itself. Dialogflow's NLP runs in the cloud - there is nothing local that it can "do".

However, you can create a launcher app that does this sort of thing by opening the microphone and sending either the stream or a speech-to-text version to Dialogflow through the [Detect Intent API](https://dialogflow.com/docs/sdks#detect_intent_and_agent_apis). Dialogflow can determine an Intent that would handle this and pass that information back to your launcher, and your launcher can then locate the app and start it.

I'm not sure how practical this would be, however. Microsoft already has this feature built-in with Cortana, and Google is building the Assistant into ChromeOS which will do this as well. While I'm not aware of Apple doing this, I may just have missed an announcement that Siri does this as well. And if there isn't someone who is doing this for Linux using some local speech-to-text libraries, it sounds like the perfect opportunity to do so.

Comment: Ok since i still a newbie to DialogFlow, i have a few queries:

1) What programming software can i use to create a launcher app?

2) Is there a tutorial for using the Detect Intent API?

Comment: Typically, asking new questions in the comments are frowned upon. We request you update your original question with as much new details as you can and include a comment in the answers that you've updated it, so other people who may have similar questions can easily see the updates. Updates should be directly relevant to the original question. If not - feel free to ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You may try and use different Dialogflow clients available on their [GitHub](https://github.com/dialogflow/) page. [Java Client 2](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-java-client-v2) may be helpful to start your work. However, you will be required to write your own UI code and have to consume Dialogflow API.